# Material UI <TextField /> the label that I am giving it is showing outside of my box

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

The Component in question

```
<TextField size="small" 
           id="outlined-basic" 
           label="Name" 
           name="rigName"
           variant="outlined" 
               style={{ width: '33%', paddingLeft: '3%', paddingRight: '4%' }}
               InputLabelProps={{ style: { fontSize: 12 } }}
/>
```

I have a div wrapping it with this CSS

```
.textFields {
  display: inline;
  /* width: 100% !important; */
}
```

How it looks right now [image]

The goal is to make it atleast 1/3 of the way into the box
When I inspect it with Chrome, I find this element
`.MuiInputLabel-formControl` with a property of `left: 0;`

I've tried putting `left: auto` into the wrapper CSS but that doesn't work. and whenever I try putting in the InputLabelProps Style, it yells at me

Sandbox for example
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sinoussi-usmwp

Comment: Could you provide an online demo which may help a lot?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sinoussi-usmwp

Comment: Ah, figured it out after making the sandbox, it was the padding I added!

Comment: Hah, nice for you